# Is there a way to enable Windows CUA keys in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

My years of habit in Windows have imprinted on me that Ctrl+X == Cut, Ctrl+C == Copy, and Ctrl+V == Paste everywhere (including Vim and Emacs). Now I've started using Ubuntu at work, and this has been the single biggest stumbling block so far. Can I somehow enable these shortcuts for all Ubuntu programs?

Comment: This is probably a bad way to teach yourself vim/emacs. What other programs are affected?

Comment: Most graphical apps that I have used honor the copy/cut/paste functionality.  However you are out of luck with Terminal apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those shortcut keys work just the same in Ubuntu.

They only don't work on the terminal which, as Ignacio explains, have deeper roots than cut, copy, and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V have *very*-long-established meanings within a terminal, which can't be overridden. You'll have to get to using Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-Shift-V instead within a terminal.